# Salvar relatório no Django Excel com filtro

Tags: python, django

Boa tarde...fiz uma função para exportar relatório em excel que deu certo, porem vem tudo que está no banco de dados, eu queria que fosse filtrado...por gentileza alguém poderia me ajudar....

função que lista meu model

```
# funcao para listas as alocacoes no template
@login_required
def listAlocacao(request):
    varios = request.GET.get('varios', None)
    context = {}
    if varios:
        alocacoes = Alocar.objects.filter(turma__curso__icontains=varios) | \
                    Alocar.objects.filter(turma__periodo__icontains=varios) | \
                    Alocar.objects.filter(turma__disciplina__icontains=varios) | \
                    Alocar.objects.filter(turma__professor__icontains=varios) | \
                    Alocar.objects.filter(dia__icontains=varios) | \
                    Alocar.objects.filter(horario__horario__icontains=varios) | \
                    Alocar.objects.filter(sala__sala__icontains=varios)
    else:
        alocacoes = Alocar.objects.all()

    context = {'alocacoes': alocacoes}
    return render(request, 'alocar/listalocacao.html', context)
```

## funcao para exportar relatorio excel

```
def export_users_xls(request):
    MDATA = datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="alocacoes.xls"'

    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    ws = wb.add_sheet('Alocacoes')

    # Sheet header, first row
    row_num = 0

    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    font_style.font.bold = True

    columns = ['BLOCO','SALA','CURSO','PERIODO','DISCIPLINA','PROFESSOR','DIA','HORARIO']

    for col_num in range(len(columns)):
        ws.write(row_num, col_num, columns[col_num], font_style)

    # Sheet body, remaining rows
    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()

    rows = Alocar.objects.all().values_list('sala__bloco__bloco','sala__sala','turma__curso','turma__periodo','turma__disciplina','turma__professor','dia','horario__horario')

    for row in rows:
        row_num += 1
        for col_num in range(len(row)):
            ws.write(row_num, col_num, row[col_num], font_style)

    wb.save(response)
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está pegando todos os registros do model `Alocar` porque está usando `.all()` no seu QuerySet em:

```
rows = Alocar.objects.all().values_list('sala__bloco__bloco','sala__sala','turma__curso','turma__periodo','turma__disciplina','turma__professor','dia','horario__horario')
```

Caso queira filtrar por algum atributo de `Alocar` você deve substituir o `.all()` por `.filter(<ATRIBUTO_DE_ALOCAR>=<VALOR_DE_FILTRAGEM>)`

Você pode ler mais sobre `filter` na documentação oficial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#filter

Comment: @malves1982....bom dia...entendi o que vc esta falando em relaçao ao (all()). minha funcao que filtra esta numa outra view...onde eu tenho o queryset filtrado, porem nao consigo puxar o relatorio filtrado dela...ate editei meu post para te mostrar...se vc puder me ajudar te agradeço, isso é um trabalho de TCC

Comment: Bom dia @ElvisDba, pelo o que entendi você chama a view `listAlocacao`, listando as alocações de alguma forma e depois faz a chamada da view `export_users_xls` para gerar o relatório.

Não vi nada que faça comunicação entre estas views informando quais `Alocar`s você está interessado.

Recomendo 1) passar a lista de IDs da primeira view para a segunda; ou 2) passar este parâmetro `varios` da primeira view para a segunda e repetir o QuerySet na segunda pra obter a filtragem que você tem na primeira.

Comment: ...minha dificuldade reside nesse ponto em questão...fazer essa comunicação..pois eu sou um pouco inexperiente com django...entendeu?